# Low bandwidth current probe design

Tags: operational-amplifier, ac, transformer, analog, design

I have the following questions about my design shown below for a cheap low bandwidth current probe:

[image: LTspice schematic for current probe]

The probe uses a split-core current transformer and is intended for simple checks on mains-powered motor control circuits.

The part numbers for the LEDs and Zener are placeholders.  My questions do not concern the low battery indicator but I would be glad to learn whether it can be done simpler. LM324 and LM358 will be used for the opamps. Because the schematic is from a simulation, I have not included decoupling capacitors for the ICs but I understand the need for them in practice.

U1 buffers the output of voltage divider R2 R3, providing Vsupply/2. The CT
output, modelled here with I1, will be referenced against this value.

U2 buffers the input from the CT, modelled with I1.  I think this buffer is
needed for accuracy, in order that the burden R1 be the only loading on the CT.

U3 and U4 amplify the signal in order to yield 50mV/A or 500mV/A outputs, depending on R8 which is selected by a switch.  Because the probe is not expected to be super accurate, 1% resistors will be used without trimmers for R8, but a trimmer will be used in series with R5 to set the initial scaling value.

U5 buffers the output of the divider R14 R16 R18 R15. R16 and R18 are a 10k
potentiometer. This is fed to a summing node together with the output of U4
to allow small dc offsets to be added to the output.

Now to my questions about the design:

1. Is my understanding correct about the need to buffer the CT output and avoid
   loading it with anything except the burden R1?  If so, am I making a mistake
   in tying it directly to the output of U1, the split rail?
2. I have researched unity gain buffers in connection with what I am doing with
   U1, U2, and U5. This has led me to understand that having no resistor in the
   feedback path will not be a problem for this low bandwidth device.  I believe
   a feedback resistor to match impedance with the input is used in high speed
   design?
3. I realize that I have nowhere quantified 'low bandwidth'.  Even a very
   low value like 10kHz would be sufficient for my needs from this device. Am I right in understanding that I can use an LTspice ac analysis to find the 3dB point for the circuit (from I1 to the output) and regard that as the bandwidth?

Comment: As my question was not attracting responses, I have edited it to remove relevant but unnecessary information. Please let me know in a comment if it is considered unacceptable on this site to post a schematic that is only readable once expanded.

Comment: FYI, this open source design may give you ideas https://www.eevblog.com/projects/ucurrent/ , it's also available off the shelf (I have no connection whatsoever).

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I saw that design during my research. Unfortunately in making my question briefer I trimmed information on the kind of measurements my design is intended for. I will restore this information.